# How to get when the validation state has changed in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, error-handling

Hi have an application that uses `MVVM`, there are 3 textboxes in the XAML all of which need to be not null, and there is a button that's submit at the bottom, I've already implemented a validator so that textbox shows error in UI with red border when they're not empty, the thing I want is, also disable the submit button when textbox is in error state

One approach I tried is to implement `IDataErrorInfo` like this

```
#region IDataErrorInfo Members

        public string Error
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                //Code here to manually disable the submit button, if the fields are empty
                return null;
            }
        }
#endregion
```

I can manually check if the textboxes are empty since they're binded to properties and I can also use a property to bind the `isEnabled` attribute of the submit button the same, but the method in `IDataErrorInfo` just doesn't get hit every time validation status changes.

Basically I can't let the method behind submit execute unless the form is valid and do it in a way that won't break things down the line

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the binding for your text boxes support validation status changes:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
<Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
```

Define your command to include a CanExecute method:

```
public ICommand SubmitCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _submitCommand ?? (_submitCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSubmitCommand, CanExecuteSubmitCommand));
    }
}
```

Add this extra call in the setter of your property **_submitCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();**

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyProperty));
        _submitCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in your view model validate your values and keep their validation result in some bool fields:

```
public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        if (propertyName == nameof(MyProperty))
        {
            _isValidMyProperty = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyProperty);
            if (!_isValidMyProperty )
            {
                return "Invalid value";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the CanExecute method return if the Submit command can be executed or not. The button will be automatically enabled/disabled based on the command availability:

```
private bool CanExecuteSubmitCommand()
{            
    return _isValidMyProperty;
}
```